# How to find what's using up my RAM under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, memory

Recently my system has been rather sluggish. I have 4 GB of RAM, most of the time I don't have anything super heavy open (2 browsers with a significant amount of tabs, Java IDE, Skype etc.).

When I add the "Working set" column values in Process Explorer for the most memory-consuming processes, it doesn't even reach 2 GB. Despite this, Process Explorer tells me that 3.5 GB of physical memory is consumed.

How can I find out what's eating up my RAM?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using another system to check you RAM using RAMMap ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx ), to be honest, Windows Task Manager (CTRL + ALT + ESC) should tell you where the RAM usage is going, other than that I could only think to look at what programs you're using and see if any are subject to memory leaks.

I would also look into the rec. specs of Java IDE, Java is notorious for resource-hogging.